# What does Visual Studio 2010 do before invoking msbuild?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm having a problem with Visual Studio not invoking msbuild to actually build my solution. Invoking msbuild from the commandline results in a proper build, but in Visual Studio starting build results in an "everything is up to date" message. Manually compiling a .cpp file seems to partially or fully fix the problem.

Restarting VS2010 does not correct the problem, so I feel like VS2010 must be writing its own dependency information somewhere. By dependency information I mean what files actually require building, AKA which files have been altered since the last successful build.

Does VS2010 perform it's own dependency checking before invoking msbuild? Where does it store this information?

Comment: The question is - what it does not do? :-)

Comment: Are you asking about dependency checking as in, which projects need to be built before others, or changed file detection?

Comment: @tuxedo25: changed file detection, I will try to clarify in the post.

Comment: Are you talking about makefile project, which invokes msbuild?

Comment: No, this is a standard C++ solution consisting of a few c++ vcprojs, I assumed that visual studio would hand over the actual building to msbuild as that is what my googling has indicated.

Comment: Does it saying which Target is skipped with message that all files are up to date?

Comment: No, there is no message that anything is skipped, just that everything is up to date.

Comment: Check in the "Configuration manager" which platform are you building for... select "Debug" or "Release" and try "Rebuild all"

Comment: Dependency information works via the timestamps of files. Is your system clock playing up?

Comment: @MSalters - As I mentioned in a comment on Miguel's answer, there is no system clock issue as far as I can tell, the problem is recurring and happens on several PCs.

Comment: @freerider: Rebuild All does do a proper rebuild but eventually incremental builds will fail to properly build dirty targets.

Answer (score 1):

To force a build to occur from the Visual Studio GUI you can select "Rebuild All". That will trigger compilation of all your source files.

The problem with regular builds not working could be related to incorrect clock settings in your PC. Make sure your system clock is correct, including the time zone. Then do a project 'clean' and try to build again.

Comment: There is no timestamp problem, I've verified the issue on several PCs. I have *not* seen it since installing VS2010 SP1, but I haven't found anything in the release notes to indicate that this issue specifically was fixed.

Comment: Indeed SP1 does not fix the problem. The problem may be .sln specific.

Answer (score 0):

My Dad says to check your "obj folder" and clean it out. VS2010 is seeing that there are things on there so it assumes there's nothing new to build.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this kind of behavior occasionally, though I can't explain how it gets corrupted.

Try deleting all the intermediate files:  everything in the `Debug` and `Release` directories, plus the project name files of types `.suo`, `.ncb`, and `.aps`.  Then rebuild all.

If you are experiencing the same behavior as I do, this tends to make VS work properly for awhile—a few weeks or 50-100 builds (whichever comes first).

Comment: Do not delete the `.sln` file! That's the Visual Studio Solution file that defines which projects need to be built, plus several more important things.

Comment: @Spire: I have removed it from my answer:  I glanced at a C++ project and its content looks unnecessary:  Isn't `.vcproj` the only necessary glue?

Comment: The `.sln` file contains configuration information (e.g., `Debug`and `Release`), platform information (e.g., `Win32` and `x64`), project dependencies, and other important things that usually cannot be automatically re-created. To address your question about `.vcproj`: In Visual Studio 2010, the `.vcxproj` and `.vcxproj.filters` files should not be deleted either.